# Number of different shapes for a full binary tree with height n

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to understand the solution to the following problem:
[image]

continuation:
[image]

As per the document, the correct answer for *(4)* is *(a)*:

[image]

But I don't get why there's the $-s_{n-1}$ at case 3. $T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent, so where would that subtraction come from? Is the solution correct?

Comment: Have you tried to see if it works for $n=4$?

Comment: I will give it a try, but there are a lot of possible shapes...

Comment: Well, try $n=3$ first.  BTW, it seems to me that you're right, but I'm not sure.  I'll try small examples too.

Comment: I haven't tried for n = 3, as the problem statement mentions it should hold for n > 3. Why it would work for n = 4 but not n = 3, I don't know either.

Comment: Yes, that seems like a mistake in the statement.  I don't see why it wouldn't work for $n=2$ also.

Comment: This is sequence [A001699 in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001699). You are correct that the $-s_{n-1}$ is unnecessary.

Comment: @shoteyes I was just about to make exactly the same comment

Comment: @shoteyes, but isn't that the number of (all) binary trees of height n? These are full binary trees, there's an additional condition to them.

Comment: It should say *full*, *rooted* binary trees on the OEIS page but it doesn’t. You can tell it’s not for all rooted binary trees because the first three terms $1$, $1$, and $3$ wouldn’t makes sense otherwise.

Comment: @shoteyes it can't possibly be the correct sequence. Look at the [illustration](https://oeis.org/A001699/a001699.gif).

Comment: That illustration is for the sequence when you start with $1, 3, \ldots$, but the true sequence starts with $1, 1, 3, \ldots.$ It’s not a coincidence that the sequence for full, rooted binary trees is the same as the one for all rooted binary trees but shifted by $1$.

Comment: @shoteyes holy shit, I think you're right. I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that they are wrong. You can already see that their proposed recurrence does not work for $n=2$:

$$
s_2\stackrel{?}= 2s_1\cdot s_0+s_1^2-s_1
\\
3\neq 2\cdot 1\cdot 1+1^2-1
$$

Now, I know that they only claim the recurrence should work for $n>3$. But there is no reason a recurrence of this type should have a cutoff at $3$. The fact that the alternate recurrence
$$
s_n=2s_{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}s_k + s_{n-1}^2
$$
does work for $n=1$ and $n=2$ suggests that it might be more correct in general. More importantly, as far as I can tell your reasoning about the trees being independent is correct. The only reason to subtract $s_{n-1}^2$ would be to get rid of the possibility of trees where the left and right subtrees are identical, but this was not a stated restriction.